# how can control sendForm with javaScript (allow or denied)

Tags: javascript

how can i,m control send form with javaScript
pay attention : i,m not want send form or stop for send form but i,m want controll allow or notAllow for sendForm

```
let idForm='formPasswordForget';
let form=document.getElementById(idForm);

stopSendForm(form){
    console.log('run stopSendForm')
    form.addEventListener("click",event=>{
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}

allowSendForm(form)
{
    console.log('run allowSendForm')
    // ?? how we delete listener click on function stopSedForm ???
    // ?? and how delete event.preventDefault() ???
    /*this.form.addEventListener("click",event=>{
        return true;
    });*/
}
```

Comment: `form.removeEventListener("click")` is what you're looking for?

Comment: That won't work - `removeEventListener` needs 2 arguments. Here's the error message - `Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeEventListener' on 'EventTarget': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 29,
  "colno": 8
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can't exactly delete an event listener that way. What you have to do is wrap your executable function code in an actual function with a name, and then assign it through a reference to `addEventListener`. This will allow you to use `removeEventListener`, where you pass in the same conditions as `addEventListener` on the same element.

```js
let idForm = 'formPasswordForget';
let form = document.getElementById(idForm);

function stopSubmit(evt) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

function stopSendForm(form) {
  console.log('run stopSendForm');
  form.addEventListener("submit", stopSubmit);
}

function allowSendForm(form) {
  console.log('run allowSendForm');
  form.removeEventListener("submit", stopSubmit);
}

function switchState(evt) {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    stopSendForm(form);
  } else {
    allowSendForm(form);
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="formPasswordForget">
  <input type="email" value="example@gmail.com"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="stopSend" onchange="switchState()"><label for="stopSend">Stop the form from sending?</label><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

that ?

```js
const myForm     = document.getElementById('my-form')
  ,   formDenied = document.getElementById('form-denied')
  ;

myForm.addEventListener('submit',evt=>
  {
  if (formDenied.checked) 
    {
    evt.preventDefault()
    return
    }

  // ... possible other code before submit  
       
  })
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" id="form-denied"> form denied </label>  

<form action="" id="my-form">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: While that does work, it seems that OP wants a function to trigger/untrigger this depending on the case with the way they phrased the question. Also, the "other code" won't run when the box is checked, because the function was returned.

Comment: @Endothermic_Dragon It would really surprise me if we could forbid the occurrence of a submit event

Comment: Isn't that what your code did with `evt.preventDefault()`? I'm confused about what you are trying to say. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @Endothermic_Dragon My answer concerns the PO question: deactivate a submission. But the PO imagines that he can deactivate the submission event, which is impossible